# Pattern to split string and store in HashMap Java 8

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-8, java-stream

I want to split the below string and store it in a HashMap:

```
String currentString= "firstName-lastName-rollNum-departmentNum=firstName1-lastName1-rollNum1-departmentNum1";
```

I want my output to be store in map, like first string before hyphen (-)(firstName) and first string after (=)(firstName1),......... i.e.,

```
{firstName=firstName1,lastName=lastName1,rollNum=rollNum1,departmentNum=departmentNum1}
```

Below code doesn't work for my pattern:

```
Map<String,String> mapVal= null;
mapVal = Pattern.compile("\\s*=\\s*")
                .splitAsStream(currentString.trim())
                .map(s -> s.split("-", 2))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a.length>1? a[1]: ""));
```

Once I split the string I don't understand how I can get my required values together as shown above. I apologize if you don't get my question.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 7):

A simpler approach is to just use split with standard arrays.

```
String[] keyValues = currentString.split("=", 2);
String[] keys = keyValues[0].split("-");
String[] values = keyValues[1].split("-", keys.length);
Map<String, String> map = IntStream.range(0, keys.length).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> keys[i], i -> values[i]));
```

There's no error checking in this but hopefully it'll give you the general idea.

Answer (score 3):

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54122739/2711488), a plain array based operation may be much simpler here.

But if you insist on a Stream solution, it may look like

```
Map<String,String> mapVal= Stream.of(currentString)
    .map(s0 -> Arrays.stream(s0.split("\\s*=\\s*", 2))
        .map(s1 -> s1.split("-")).toArray(String[][]::new))
    .flatMap(a -> IntStream.range(0, a[0].length)
        .mapToObj(i -> new String[]{ a[0][i], i < a[1].length? a[1][i]: "" }))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]));
```

Comment: Honestly, I left that as a task to figure out how could I convert that solution to stream, and now that I've had a look at this, I have another to understand this better and see how well this goes with a more generic approach. Of course I could see `Stream.of` here as well, but primarily thinking along the lines of `split` and the `map`pings.

Comment: @nullpointer well, take sprinter’s solution, refactor the two `currentString.split("=")` expressions into a local value declared before that, then, convert all these steps into a Stream operation. Since a Stream cannot hold a pair of two elements, you have to use an array to hold `keys` and `values` (two-dimensional as these two variables already have an array type). After that conversion, refactor it two use a stream operation for the `String[][]` creation, to not have two `split('-')` operations anymore. Then, you’re at my answer…

Answer (score 2):

Another solution :

```
String[] arr = Arrays.toString(currentString.split("="))
                     .replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").replaceAll(",", "-")
                     .split("-");

Map<String, String> collect = IntStream.range(0, arr.length / 2).boxed()
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> arr[i], i -> arr[i + arr.length / 2]));
```

Here we split the string first based on `=`, then we use the `.toString()` to remove all occurrences of `]` and`[` from the String. Now we replace `,` with `-` so we can split the resulting String based on `-`

After the first statement the array `arr` looks like :

> [firstName, lastName, rollNum, departmentNum,  firstName1, lastName1,
>   rollNum1, departmentNum1]

Now all we need to do is to iterate over the resulting array(`arr`) upto the mid-point(`arr.length / 2`) and map it using Collectors.toMap

Comment: Yup, they do. Just that I still find the solution by sprinter much simpler.

Comment: @nullpointer yeah, sprinter’s solution is much simpler. I had to read this string manipulation code multiple times to understand that it is intended to be an inefficient variant of `String[] arr = Arrays.stream(currentString.split("=")) .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("-"))) .toArray(String[]::new);`, but not even a correct one, as it inserts a space character to the first value. Not to speak of what happens when using it with a different input values containing a `'['`, `']'`, or `','`…

Answer (score 0):

Other way would be like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*=\\s*");
int index = currentString.indexOf("=");
Map<Boolean, List<String>> map = pattern
            .splitAsStream(currentString.trim())
            .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.split("-")))
            .collect(partitioningBy(s -> currentString.indexOf(s) > index));
```

this step result is:

> ```
> {
>   false=[firstName, lastName, rollNum, departmentNum],
>
>   true=[firstName1, lastName1, rollNum1, departmentNum1]
> }
> ```

and then convert previous result to final result:

```
IntStream.range(0, map.get(true).size())
            .boxed()
            .collect(toMap(i -> map.get(false).get(i), i -> map.get(true).get(i)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Map<String, String> toMap(String str) {
    String[] arr = str.split("[-=]");
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0, j = arr.length / 2; j < arr.length; i++, j++)
        map.put(arr[i], arr[j]);

    return map;
}
```

Comment: instead `j = 4;` use `arr.length/2;`

Comment: It does not matter. I like my solution, because no need to do `arr.length / 2` 4 times